# TSQL various Max date options not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to get the Maximum date and details on my report but they still return all entries within a given time span instead of just the latest entry details.

the table name is `dbo.vwPupil_EventType`:

```
EventID (int,not null)
PupilID (int,not null)
EventDate (datetime,null)
Header Note(text,null)
Event Type (varchar(100),null)
Module ID (int,null)
```

1st attempt generated error msg 306:

> the text, ntext and image data types cannot be compared

```
SELECT   [Pupil ID], [Event Date],[Header Note], [Module ID], [Event ID] AS ID
FROM     dbo.vwPupil_EventType EV
WHERE    ([Module ID] = 22)
GROUP BY [Event ID],[Pupil ID], [Event Date],[Header Note],[Module ID]  
HAVING   [Event Date]IN (SELECT MAX([Event Date])
                         FROM     dbo.vwPupil_EventType
                         WHERE    EV.[Event ID] = [Event ID])
ORDER    BY [Pupil ID]
```

Tried these other 2 options but still getting all entries within a date span instead of just the latest one:

```
SELECT   [Pupil ID], [Event Date], CAST([Header Note]AS VARCHAR(100))NOTE, [Module ID], [Event ID] AS ID
FROM     dbo.vwPupil_EventType EV
WHERE    ([Module ID] = 22)
GROUP BY [Event ID],[Pupil ID], [Event Date],CAST([Header Note]AS VARCHAR(100)),[Module ID]  
HAVING   [Event Date]IN (SELECT MAX([Event Date])
                         FROM     dbo.vwPupil_EventType
                         WHERE    EV.[Event ID] = [Event ID])
ORDER BY [Pupil ID]
```

then tried

```
SELECT   [Pupil ID], MAX(CAST([Event Date] AS DATETIME)), CAST([Header Note]AS VARCHAR(100))NOTE, [Module ID], [Event ID] AS ID
FROM     dbo.vwPupil_EventType EV
WHERE    ([Module ID] = 22)
GROUP BY [Event ID],[Pupil ID], [Event Date],CAST([Header Note]AS VARCHAR(100)),[Module ID]  
HAVING   [Event Date]IN (SELECT MAX([Event Date])
                         FROM     dbo.vwPupil_EventType
                         WHERE    EV.[Event ID] = [Event ID])
ORDER BY [Pupil ID]
```

Comment: I think no need of where clause in sub query and also if `[Event Date]` is not in datetime type then it should cast in subquery as well as in having clause

Comment: hi JaydipJ, thank you for your reply but response does not help much...with being new to sql, an example of what it should look like would help

Answer (score 0):

This is typically solved using a window function:

```
select [Pupil ID], [Event Date],[Header Note], [Module ID], [ID]
from (
  SELECT   [Pupil ID], [Event Date],[Header Note], [Module ID], [Event ID] AS ID, 
           row_number() over (partition by [Pupil ID] order by [Event Date] desc) as rn
  FROM     dbo.vwPupil_EventType EV
  WHERE    [Module ID] = 22
) t
where rn = 1;
```

If there are multiple rows with the same "max date", you'll only get one of them. If you want all of them returned use `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()`

Comment: hello a-horse...thank you for providing your example...I have not really worked with over partition yet but will give it a go

Comment: Hello, after applying your script, now get message....Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'dbo.vwPupil_EventType'.

Comment: @newangie: then apparently you do not have a table named `dbo.vwPupil_EventType` despite what you stated in your question

Comment: hello you are correct...have just retried it with the correct table and it does what I need, namely returned 1 line showing the latest entry...thank you so much for your patience and assistance with this

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you requirement correctly they this may help you

```
SELECT   [Pupil ID],
         [Event Date],
         CAST([Header Note]AS VARCHAR(100)) NOTE, 
         [Module ID], 
         [Event ID] AS ID
FROM     dbo.vwPupil_EventType EV
WHERE    [Module ID] = 22
         AND CAST([Event Date] AS DATETIME) = (SELECT MAX(CAST([Event Date] AS DATETIME))
                                                FROM dbo.vwPupil_EventType)
ORDER BY [Pupil ID]
```